# Область видимости и внутренние функции в JS

Tags: javascript, base64

Функция не возвращает base64 строку по всей видимости из за того что canvas находится вне зоне видимости внешней функции, как сделать canvas видимым и вернуть корректную base64 строку?

```
    function resizeImage(im,p) {

        var imgObj = new Image();

        imgObj.onload = function() {

            if (p=='preview') {
                var MAX_WIDTH = 80;
                var MAX_HEIGHT = 80;
            }

            if (p=='max_size') {
                var MAX_WIDTH = 1305;
                var MAX_HEIGHT = 1305;
            }

            var width = imgObj.width;
            var height = imgObj.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
              if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                  width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                  height = MAX_HEIGHT;
              }
            }

            console.log(width);
            console.log(height);
            console.log('resizing');

            // create an off-screen canvas
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // set its dimension to target size
            canvas.width = MAX_WIDTH;
            canvas.height = MAX_HEIGHT;

            //цвет канваса
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,MAX_WIDTH,MAX_HEIGHT);


            // draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
            ctx.drawImage(imgObj, (MAX_WIDTH - width)/2 , (MAX_HEIGHT-height)/2, width, height);
          }

        imgObj.src=im;
        return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', '1');
    }
```

Comment: приведите пример значения параметра `im`

Comment: im - base64 входящего изображения вида "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ....."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `onload` будет вызвана асинхронно (т.е. код будет продолжать выполняться сразу после присвоения `onload = function` и ждать загрузки изображения не будет), поэтому в `return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', '1');` и в расширении области видимости переменной `canvas` никакого смысла нет.

Я не знаю цели использования этой функции, но возможно вам стоит модифицировать её как-то так:

```
imgObj.onload = function() {

  // код изменения размера
  // ...

  this.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', '1')
}
```

Т.е. использовать значение base64 уже внутри callback функции `onload` не пытаясь вернуть это значение через `return` функции `resizeImage`.

Comment: Назначение функции получить входящий base64 модифицировать его согласно второго параметра и вернуть модифицированный base64

Comment: В принципе функция resizeImage выполняет эту функцию и без и обработчика и внутренней функции. Но из за того что скрипту требуется время на вставку в DOM нового src скрипт "проскальзывает" и отображает изображение через раз.

Comment: @Mike вы же собираетесь где-то потом использовать новое значение base64. Если нужно его где-то отобразись или передать в другую функцию (цепочка callbackов), то надежнее всего сделать всё это изнутри onload, иначе блокировки вкладки браузера не избежать.

Comment: Вы правы, вынес действия за рамки функции resizeImage , спасибо что указали верное направление.